# If I'd like to see a "do my homework" question answered, is it OK if I fake the OP's own attempt?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

That's it, more or less. I came across a question consisting solely of the task, yet found it rather interesting. So I gave it a try, but failed. I am thinking about adding this attempt to the question, to eventually get some people look into it. Do there exist any guidelines on that?

Comment: I personally would have preferred a separate well written question. If the question you saw has answers already your addition might be out of place. If it has none, it should be closed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I did that once on another SE, my question then got closed as duplicate. But thank you for the input.

Comment: If you establish in your post that the current answers are insufficient, there's no reason to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Related older discussion: [Editing someone else's question to add context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21106/editing-someone-elses-question-to-add-context)

Answer (score 8):

As Asaf suggested: post your own question. Since *you* are the one who's really interested in it, you should also be the one deciding which answer gets accepted, etc.

Do include a link to the question, stating that it is a source of your question, and adding what you have found about it so far.